# Book about a boy who saves dolphins by becoming Poseidon/Neptune?

Tags: story-identification, books

The book was part of a series where children would shape-shift into other people. In this book a boy tries to save some dolphins so Poseidon grants him the power to become him? I remember that the cover was orange and that it showed the boy transforming into Poseidon. Other books in the series was a girl who shape shifted into her friend and a boy who shape-shifting into historical figures like Abraham Lincoln.
(To be honest I'm not sure if they used the name Poseidon or Neptune.)
-The cover was orange and it showed a picture of a boy's silhouette changing into Poseidon

Comment: While you've started us off with some good details, we could use some more such as when you may have read the book, or when it was published? If you haven't already, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can add in any additional details.